# How to zip but not in pair?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let a

```
Seq( Seq(1, 2, 5) , Seq(3, 4, 5) , Seq(2, 1, 0) )
```

I'd want to get :

```
Seq( Seq(1, 3, 2) , Seq(2, 4, 1) , Seq(5, 5, 0) )
```

For the moment I wrote this :

```
points.reduce((point_1, point_2) => point_1.zip(point_2))
```

With : `points` the `Seq[Seq[Double]]` and `point_1` and `point_2` the `Seq[Double]`.

It returns an error because Scala's interpreter seems to try to make a pair with a `Seq[(Double, Double)]` and `Double` (I think). In my example, it tries to make a pair with `Seq( (1, 3) )` and `2`. I can be wrong but it's my interpretation of the problem for now.

Well, how to solve this bug ? I feel like I need to use `flatten`, no ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard library can do that for you.

```
Seq( Seq(1, 2, 5) , Seq(3, 4, 5) , Seq(2, 1, 0) ).transpose
//res0: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 3, 2), List(2, 4, 1), List(5, 5, 0))
```

**update**

If you're intent on doing it yourself, in a functional fashion, here's one way.

```
val ssi: Seq[Seq[Int]] = Seq(Seq(1, 2, 5), Seq(3, 4, 5), Seq(2, 1, 0))

ssi.zipWithIndex.map{case (s,x) =>
  s.indices.map(ssi(_)(x))
}
```

Comment: In functional paradigm, e.g. with only `map` and `reduce` (my teacher said every program can be written thanks to these both methods, so it's possible to do what I want with only these functions)

Comment: As you can see, it can be done with `map` and `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using `map` and `fold`,

```
val seqInput = Seq( Seq(1, 2, 5) , Seq(3, 4, 5) , Seq(2, 1, 0) )
// seqInput: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 5), List(3, 4, 5), List(2, 1, 0))

val seqOutput = seqInput
  .map(s => Seq(s))
  .fold(
    seqInput.head.map(_ => Seq.empty[Int])
  )({
    case (acc, seq) => acc.zipWithIndex.map({ case (accSeq, i) => accSeq :+ seq.head(i) })
  })
// seqOutput: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 3, 2), List(2, 4, 1), List(5, 5, 0))
```